# Win32 console app living on server, do I need to rebuild in order to update app.config?

Tags: c#, winapi, console

I have a service app that runs nightly and I wanted to change some of the connection strings that reside in app.config, I should be able to just locate the file and change it without having to rebuild and redeploy more than just that file right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's right.  If you're changing configuration settings in a settings file, you do not need to recompile.

If it were a Windows Service, you would need to stop and restart it, but for a console app, it will read the configuration settings every time it's launched. (In your case, presumably through a scheduled task or other scheduling software)